# Trying to access "firebase.firestore.Timestamp" using Typescript. Error: Property 'Timestamp' does not exist on type '() => Firestore'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm converting my React + Firebase project to Typescript.

This line used to work just fine on JS.

```
const todayTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
```

But after converting to Typescript, I'm getting the following error:

```
const todayTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

// Property 'Timestamp' does not exist on type '() => Firestore'.
```

[image]

**Note:** `firebase` is of type `firebase.app.App`

[image]

See firebase docs reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore

[image]

It's like Typescript is not finding the types and classes for `firebase.firestore`. See what is available:

[image]

**QUESTION**

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're using `firebase` is not correct for accessing types.  You're not showing here the way that you fully define it in your code (we can't see what you're doing in `useFirebase()`), but it looks like you're using the result of `initializeApp()`, which returns an instance of App.  That's not going to help you work with the Timestamp type.

Normally, `firebase` is the result of an import like this, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize), which gives you access to the firebase namespace:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firbase/firestore"
```

Then you can work with Timestamp using that `firebase` namespace:

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Doug. I'm using it like that because I reuse that code on server (cloud-function) to implement SSR. And I get an error on the Node environment if I `import * as firebase from "firebase/app"` in any of my `<App/>` files. So I only import it once in my `index.tsx` file and provide via `props` to `<App firebase={firebase}/>` which then provides it via `useContext` and it gets consumed using my `useFirebase()` hook. Does the documentation include a guide on how to implement the `firebase import` if you are re-using that code on server? Thanks again.

Comment: You can't really "reuse" code between client and server, even if they are both TypeScript.  The client and server SDKs have different APIs, even if they look similar.  You will have to follow the conventions of the provided SDK.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. Just found out what I was doing wrong. I was under the impression that it was not possible to `import firebase` on a cloud function. I mean, I'll use `firebase-admin` on my cloud function, but I've probably experienced some error before and got the impression that the error was caused by the `import firebase` statement. I'll get rid of the `useFirebase` hook and `import` it directly from now on.

Answer (score 3):

For firebase v9 it is: import {  Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

Answer (score 0):

For firebase 9.10 onwords

Try this

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
```